# How can I keep my menu from appearing on .navigation-bar>ul>li:hover?

Tags: html, css

When users hover my sub menu, the menu shows.  I want the sub-nav to show only when the main nav is hovered.

For example, when "About" is hovered, it should display "Me, Us, and Them."  But I should never be able to hover "Me, Us, or Them" WITHOUT hovering "About".  Once the "About" is hovered, you should be able to hover "Me, Us, and Them" and they NOT fade away again.

```css
li, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.navigation-bar > ul {
    display: table-cell;
    cursor: default;
}
.navigation-bar > ul > li {
    width: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.navigation-bar > ul:hover > li {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```

```html
<li class="navigation-bar">
    <ul>About
        <li>Me</li>
        <li>Us</li>
        <li>Them</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Find
        <li>Me</li>
        <li>Us</li>
        <li>Them</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Shop
        <li>Shirts</li>
        <li>Pants</li>
        <li>Hats</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Contact
        <li>Me</li>
        <li>Us</li>
        <li>Them</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I'm not quite sure how to ask this.  I hope you understand the question.

### The sub menus should only show when the main (always shown) part is hovered.

### No jQuery please.

Comment: I am getting, what do you want can you please clarify.

Comment: The sub menus should only show when the main (always shown) part is hovered, @Maddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood your question and will be my best to answer.

According to what I have seen it looks like you have a wrong hover area. The reason is that you are using the :hover on ul and your structure looks wrong.

First of all the .navigation-bar is just an li without any wrapping ul. This is an error, it should be ul, the menus should be li and then the dropdown menu should be ul and li

You are also using table-cell which is giving the li a lot of width that is why there is a wrong clickable area.

I have created the code for please have a look, I tried it on my computer and it is working fine

```
<ul class="navigation-bar">
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Them</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Find</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Them</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Them</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>    
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Them</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


li, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.navigation-bar:after{
    clear:both;
    content:'';
    display:block;
}
.navigation-bar > li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:5%;
}
.navigation-bar > li > ul  {
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    position:absolute;
    top::0;
    left:0;
        margin:0;
    padding:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.navigation-bar > li:hover > ul  {
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:0s;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

The rest of the changes you can do according to your requirement.

Again please note I answered this question according to what I understood, if I am wrong the please forgive me and explain again, so that I will try to answer better

Answer (score 1):

Well first off your HTML and CSS are a bit goofy.

But your actual issue is that `visibility: hidden` does not prevent your submenu from getting mouse events.

**EDIT:** Just noticed you have a fade effect. That makes things a little more complicated because you cannot transition to or from `display: none`. Kyojimaru has suggested a hack using the max-height property which is your best option if you care about old browsers.

The modern way to do this (shown below) is to just use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property. Make sure you check [support for pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events) before you use it. If you need your site to work on IE10 and below, you’re better off using [Kyojimaru’s hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27310244/746356).

HTML:

```
<nav>
   <span>
     <a href="#">About</a>
    <menu>
        <a href="#">Me</a>
        <a href="#">Us</a>
        <a href="#">Them</a>
    </menu>
  </span>

  <span>
    <a href="#">Find</a>
    <menu>
        <a href="#">Me</a>
        <a href="#">Us</a>
        <a href="#">Them</a>
    </menu>
  </span>

  <span>
    <a href="#">Shop</a>
    <menu>
        <a href="#">Shirts</a>
        <a href="#">Pants</a>
        <a href="#">Hats</a>
    </menu>
  </span>

  <span>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <menu>
        <a href="#">Me</a>
        <a href="#">Us</a>
        <a href="#">Them</a>
    </menu>
  </span>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
/*  Layout
------------------------------------------- */
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1; /* display menu above any page content */
}

nav menu a {
  display: block;
}


/*  Aesthetics
------------------------------------------- */
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;
}


/*  Interaction
------------------------------------------- */
nav menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

nav span:hover menu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/seqoqi/9/edit?html,css,output

Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's all because you're using `visibility: hidden`. This won't have the same effect with `display: none` which will remove the `element` completely from the flow.

With `visibility: hidden`, the `element` will still be there but you just can't see it, so when it's hidden, the `li` will still be there with the `auto height`, this will cause it to trigger the `:hover` on `ul` if you hover on the `hidden li` because the `li` is the `child` of the `ul`, so if you `hover` over `li`, it means you also `hover` over `ul` and cause the problem that you get.

The way to solve this problem is either using `display: none` and `display: block` like answered by [Sanjeev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309124/how-can-i-keep-my-menu-from-appearing-on-navigation-barullihover/27310159#27310159), but it won't have the `fade effect`.

If you want to still have the `fade effect`, you can set the `max-height` of the `li` to 0 when not hovered, and when hovered, set it to something far from your element height, like `1000px` or more.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/p7ucbwdd/) on how to use the `max-height` which will preserve the `fade effect`

***Note**: As noted by Zaqk, `display: table-cell` is not the proper way to achieve the `UI`, you can change it to `display: inline-block` like answered by Zaqk [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309124/how-can-i-keep-my-menu-from-appearing-on-navigation-barullihover/27310169#27310169).

```css
li, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.navigation-bar > ul {
    display: table-cell;
    cursor: default;
}
.navigation-bar > ul > li {
    width: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear, max-height 0.5s linear;
    max-height: 0;
}
.navigation-bar > ul:hover > li {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:0s;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<li class="navigation-bar">
    <ul>About
        <li>Me</li>
        <li>Us</li>
        <li>Them</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Find
        <li>Me</li>
        <li>Us</li>
        <li>Them</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Shop
        <li>Shirts</li>
        <li>Pants</li>
        <li>Hats</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Contact
        <li>Me</li>
        <li>Us</li>
        <li>Them</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Already added this comment to another answer on here, `display: table-cell` is not appropriate for this UI.

Comment: @Zaqx, I just show what the problem are and way to solve it. Updated the answer with your information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is you should not use 
 **visiblity:hidden**  in your  **.navigation-bar > ul > li**.
Using that simply makes your list items (`<li></li>`)invisible.
You should use **display:none** and **display:block**

See the modified code snippet which is working as you are expecting.

```css
li, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.navigation-bar > ul {
    display: table-cell;
    cursor: default;
}
.navigation-bar > ul > li {
    width: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.navigation-bar > ul:hover > li {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```

```html
<li class="navigation-bar">
    <ul>About
        <li>Me</li>
        <li>Us</li>
        <li>Them</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Find
        <li>Me</li>
        <li>Us</li>
        <li>Them</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Shop
        <li>Shirts</li>
        <li>Pants</li>
        <li>Hats</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Contact
        <li>Me</li>
        <li>Us</li>
        <li>Them</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: `display: table-cell` is not appropriate for this UI.

Comment: Yes, but I only wanted to show what he was expecting.

Comment: I would expect an answer that follows best practices or at least indicates where deviating.